# Caching not working on production

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I use `Cache` from `System.Web.Caching` to cache some data from database. And when I run application on local machine from `Visual Studio` it works fine.

But when I run it on production on `IIS` I get `Null pointer exception` at this line:

```
cache.Insert("Postnumbers", postnumbers, dependency,
             DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
             CacheItemPriority.Default, PostnumberRemovedCallback);
```

I checked `cache`, `postnumbers` and `dependency` and they are not null. Anyone knows what can cause this problem?

Stacktrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Solvent.Model.Persistance.General.Entities.GeneralData.LoadPostnumbers() in C:\Solvent\Solvent\Solvent.Model\Persistance\General\Entities\GeneralData.cs:39
   Solvent.Model.SolventInitializer.InitializeCache() in C:\Solvent\Solvent\Solvent.Model\Context\SolventInitializer.cs:153
   Solvent.Model.SolventInitializer.Initialize() in C:\Solvent\Solvent\Solvent.Model\Context\SolventInitializer.cs:105
   Solvent.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Solvent\Solvent\Solvent\Global.asax.cs:42
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace

Comment: @Fildor Cache, postnumbers and dependency are not null, I wrote that.

Comment: @haim770 I only get this: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] No more info in error message.

Comment: @Aleksa Ah, overread cache ... sorry.

Comment: @Aleksa There is no "... in BlahDiBlubbb at line X ... " ?

Comment: @Fildor There is, the line number where cache.Insert is. The line I wrote in post. And after that NullReferenceException.

Comment: Can you post that log, starting from some lines above and until some lines after?

Comment: Sure, it is in post now, I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I replaced `var cache = new Cahce(); cache.Insert()` with `HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert()`. 
But I still don't know why first way works on local and not on production.